# Program to generate nCk combinations of k numbers varying from 1 to n

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, matlab

My function definition looks like
 `nxt_comb[] = Combination(comb[1:k],n)`

This function should give the next combination which comes after the input combination `comb` (array). The `n` elements of `comb` takes values from 1 to `n`.

Example:

- if function is called as `a = Combination([1,3,4,6],8)`, then `a = [1,3,4,7]`
- if function is called as `a = Combination([1,3,4,8],8)`, then `a = [1,3,5,6]`
- if function is called as `a = Combination([1,3,7,8],8)`, then `a = [1,4,5,6]`
- if function is called as `a = Combination([3,6,7,8],8)`, then `a = [4,5,6,7]`

The input combination will never be the last combination. That is, in the above case the input will be never `[5,6,7,8]`.

Also, if the input is all zeros, the function must output the first combination that is `[1,2,....,k]`.

Edit: What I am looking for is the logic. The implementation can be in either C/C++ or MATLAB.

Comment: what has this anything to do with C or C++?

Comment: @TheOne it is part of a big program. I need to generate the next combination given a particular combination and the maximum value of numbers

Comment: and what has that anything to do with C and/or C++? the object of question is neither of those

Comment: The code from the question seems to be neither C/C++ nor Matlab. @BastinJoseph: Are you looking for a Matlab or C/C++ solution?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry for the confusion. What I am looking for is the logic. The implementation can be in either C/C++ or Matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside the last requirement about starting with all 0's, which is a trivial extra check, the algorithm is:

1. By searching backwards, find the largest `i` such that `comb[i]<i+n-k` (using 1-based indexing; adjust if you're using C). If you can't find one, you're at the last combination.
2. Increment comb[i], and then working from `j = i+1` up to `k`, set `comb[j]` to `comb[j-i]+1`